# Regex remove all special characters except numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to remove all special characters (except for numbers) from a string. I have been able to get this far

```
var name = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, "");
```

but it seems that it is removing the first number and leaving all of the others.

For example:

```
name = "collection1234"; //=> collection234
```

or

```
name = "1234567"; //=> 234567
```

Comment: All characters are special in their own way, that's what momma always told me. What does "special characters" mean to you?

Comment: @sln, What do you mean?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use the global flag:

```
var name = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
                                    ^
```

If you don't want to remove numbers, add it to the class:

```
var name = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
```

Comment: I guess I asked it wrong, I want to leave all numbers in the string, but only strip special characters like ! @ # $ % ^ & * (

so `collection#24 would return collection24`

Comment: @EHerman Forget what characters you want to strip. "Special characters" is very imprecise. What characters do you want to preserve?

Comment: [^\w_ ] should do about the same as [^a-zA-Z0-9 ]

Comment: @EHerman I'm a bit at a lost now. Does that work for you or not? Jonny, yes, that's an option.

Comment: This only works if all "non-special" characters are guaranteed to be from the Latin alphabet and have no diacritics. Even strings in English language may fail this test.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Yes, hence why I'd rather not use it. For the basic texts though, it will work fine.

Answer (score 20):

To remove the special characters, try

```
var name = name.replace(/[!@#$%^&*]/g, "");
```

Comment: +1 - the answer. Althouth, its more efficent with a `+` modifier.

Comment: This will not remove whitespaces!!

Answer (score 15):

If you don't mind including the underscore as an allowed character, you could try simply:

```
result = subject.replace(/\W+/g, "");
```

If the underscore must be excluded also, then

```
result = subject.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "");
```

(Note the case insensitive flag)

Answer (score 8):

to remove symbol use tag [ ]

step:1

```
[]
```

step 2:place what symbol u want to remove eg:@ like [@]

```
[@]
```

step 3:

```
var name = name.replace(/[@]/g, "");
```

thats it

```js
var name="ggggggg@fffff"
var result = name.replace(/[@]/g, "");
console .log(result)
```

Extra Tips

To remove space (give one space into square bracket like []=>[ ])

```
[@ ]
```

It Remove Everything (using except)

```
[^place u dont want to remove]
```

eg:i remove everyting except alphabet (small and caps)

```
[^a-zA-Z ]
```

```js
var name="ggggg33333@#$%^&**I(((**gg@fffff"
var result = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
console .log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well

> text = 'the car? was big and* red!'
>
> newtext = re.sub( '[^a-z0-9]', ' ', text)
>
> print(newtext)

the car  was big and  red

Answer (score 0):

Excluding special characters:   /^[^@~`!@#$%^&*()_=+\\';:"\/?>.<,-]*$/
this regular expression helps to exclude special characters from the input.

Exclude special characters and emojis : /^([^\u2700-\u27BF\uE000-\uF8FF\uDD10-\uDDFF\u2011-\u26FF\uDC00-\uDFFF\uDC00-\uDFFF\u005D\u007C@~`!@#$%^&*()_=+[{}"\\';:"\/?>.<,-\s])*$/
this is a regular expression to exclude both special characters and emojis from the input. Given are the Unicode ranges of the emojis , mathematical symbols and symbols in other languages.