# Function to receive an array of characters and return a string with the characters a-z, A-Z and 0-9

Tags: javascript, filter, character

I am trying to create a function named `wipe` that takes in an array of characters and returns a string that contains only the valid characters: a-z, A-Z, and 0-9. Just like this:

`['A','0','-'-,'<','b','3','/'] ->  'A0b3'`

I searched online for regex and filter but I have never used them since I am new to coding and I am very very confused already. From what I read, a filter removes elements from the array but in this case I think that what is asked is just to *return a string with the valid characters a-z, A-Z and 0-9*.

Would it be something like this?

```
var wipe = function (arrayName)


   return arrayName(condition??).join('');
```

Completely (desperately) lost here! Thank you.

EDIT: is that a way to do this just doing

`return (not sure what)`

The program should not print anything and is not supposed to use const or let or anything. Just execute the function and return the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regular expressions that test whether the character is what you want.

```js
const wipe = function(arrayName) {
  return arrayName.filter(character => /^[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(character)).join("")
}

console.log(wipe(['A', '0', '-', '-', '<', 'b', '3', '/']))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problems can be solved using the regex `/[^a-z0-9]/gi`. `a-z0-9` is the pattern for all lower case alphanumeric characters, `^` in the brackets is basically "not", and `gi` means case-insensitive. Putting this pattern into the `replace` method matches any characters that are not alphanumeric and replaces them with an empty character.

```js
const wipe = function(chars) {
    return chars.join("").replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
};
console.log(wipe(['A','0','-','<','b','3','/']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this have a look [Regex remove all special characters except numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731966/regex-remove-all-special-characters-except-numbers) use join then split if needed