# Remove non-digits from collated string and only keep numbers

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need syntax or method to remove any non-numeric values from a collated varchar column and replace with zero padded 10-digit account number result. The column has letters and special characters, but I need to remove those and only keep the numbers.

I am using [LPAD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lpad.html) function `LPAD(Account_Number_Column,10,'0')` to left pad the result with zeros

| Account_Number_Column |
| --- |
| 00#9999999 |
| 000123456M |
| N/A |

| Expected_Result |
| --- |
| 0009999999 |
| 0000123456 |
| 0000000000 |

Comment: The regex to be used for this requirement can be referenced from the following SO discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731966/regex-remove-all-special-characters-except-numbers

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
select lpad(regexp_replace(Account_Number_Column,'[^\\d]*'),10,0);
```

Of course, you may want to also incorporate other elements around data quality (like ensuring your non-padded result is <= 10 characters, etc).  Whatever constitutes an acceptable result in your use case.

If you have collation, I would suggest removing it for the REGEXP function, and reapply to the resulting string.

Here's an example where if you had a collation of 'en-ci' you could strip it for the function and reapply for the result:

```
select collate(lpad(regexp_replace(collate(Account_Number,''),'[^\\d]*'),10,'0'),'en-ci');
```

Comment: I get an error "...REGEXP_REPLACE does not support collation."

Comment: omg `regexp_replace` I knew there was something much simpler I was missing!

Comment: I haven’t tried this yet, but it appears you could wrap your column with a collate statement that creates a runtime copy with no collation:

Comment: You can also specify an empty string for a collation specification (e.g. COLLATE '' or COLLATE(col1, '')), which indicates to use no collation.

Comment: I've verified you can both strip and apply collation in the same command for REGEXP processing - see edited answer above.

Comment: Have you tried the above approach that resolves the collation obstacle?

Answer (score 0):

One method is it use [REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all.html) to get the array of matching digits, and then turn that array into a string with [ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string.html), which can then be LPAD to 10

```
SELECT Account_Number_Column
    ,ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL(Account_Number_Column, '\\d'),'') as result_a
    ,LPAD(result_a,10,'0') as answer_a
FROM VALUES
    ('00#9999999'),
    ('000123456M'),
    ('N/A')
    t(Account_Number_Column);
```

gives:

| ACCOUNT_NUMBER_COLUMN | RESULT_A | ANSWER_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00#9999999 | 009999999 | 0009999999 |
| 000123456M | 000123456 | 0000123456 |
| N/A | '' | 0000000000 |

Striping the [COLLATION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/collation.html#sorting-using-utf-8-vs-locale-collation) off strings is normally bad, BUT given you only want digit's is should ok in this instance to do so via `collate(Account_Number_Column,'utf8')`

```
SELECT collate(raw, 'sp-upper') as Account_Number_Column
    ,lpad(regexp_replace(collate(Account_Number_Column,'utf8'),'[^\\d]*'),10,'0')
FROM VALUES
    ('00#9999999'),
    ('000123456M'),
    ('N/A')
    t(raw);
```

but it should be Jim's answer:

```
select lpad(regexp_replace(collate(Account_Number_Column,'utf8'),'[^\\d]*'),10,'0');
```

Comment: thank you but I get the error "... REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL does not support collation."